# Какой путь к Гугл Диску на андроид?

Tags: android, google-drive, termux

У меня такая ситуация, я загремел на госпитализацию, а ноута нет. Взял с собой клаву и мышь, докупил необходимые переходники, для подключения последних к андроид смартфону. Только чтобы начать работать - нужно подключиться к Гугл Диску, где собственно Django проект сохранён.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какой путь до Г Диска на андроидах!

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian, you ask on StackOverflow in _Russian_. ;)

Comment: Скачиваешь приложение google drive и скачиваешь

Comment: Надо скачать приложение [Google Диск](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs&hl=ru&gl=US)

Comment: `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/files/` ?

Answer (score 0):

До Android 11:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs/
```

После Android 11:

```
///_Android_data/com.google.android.apps.docs/
```